# Representing hypersurfaces as graphs

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Let $\Sigma \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a smooth, embedded, compact hypersurface. Then it can be locally written as a graph of a function. With that, I mean that for any $p \in \Sigma$ there is a neighborhood a ball $B_{r_x}(p) \subset  \mathbb{R}^2$ of radius $r_p>0$ around $x$ such that the hypersurface is locally given as the graph of a function $u$,
$$
\Sigma \cap B_{r_x}(x) = \{(z,u(z)): z \in [-r_p,r_p]\}.
$$

What I want to know is whether it is possible to bound the radius $r_p$ from below by the curvature of the hypersurface. The fact that it is possible to find such a representation follows from the implicit function theorem but it doesn't yield a lower bound on $r_p$. Is there some quantitative version of the implicit function theorem?

My idea would be the following.

After rotating and translating, it is possible to arrange that in $p=(0,0)$ the gradient of $u'(0)=0$. If we assume that the second fundamental form of $\Sigma$ is bounded by a constant, $|A| \leq C$, I am able to bound, for any $\epsilon>0$, in a ball of radius $(4 \epsilon^{-1}C)^{-1}$
$$
|u'| \leq \epsilon, \quad |u''| \leq 2 C.
$$
It seems to be possible to deduce from here, that for $Id$ being the identity map on $\mathbb{R}^2$, we get the following operator norm bound,
$$
|(z,u(z))-Id| \leq \epsilon.
$$
Hence, $(z,u(z))$ is invertible in  $[-(4 \epsilon^{-1}C)^{-1},(4 \epsilon^{-1}C)^{-1}]$. Now I don't see the arguments but I think it should be possible to bound the radius $r_p$ from below by $(4 \epsilon^{-1}C)^{-1}$.

Comment: On the top of my head there are two different theorems, which will get you what you want: 1) There is a (more ore less) quantitave version of the implicit function theorem, see Serge Lang Real and Functional analysis, Chapter 14, Lemma 1.3. 2) Allards Regularity Theorem, which is a deep result from Geometric measure theory, see Leon Simon Introduction to geometric measure theory, Thm 5.2, (see https://web.stanford.edu/class/math285/ts-gmt.pdf )

Comment: @humanStampedist Thank you for your answer. If I understand it correctly, In the source you mentioned it is already assumend that a ball of radius $\rho$ is contained in a neighborhood such that it can be represented as a graph. Is there any way to estimate the $\rho$ in terms of the curvature?

Comment: No, the theorem in Leon Simons book states in a simplified manner, that if you have estimates on the curvature on a $B_\rho$ ball and you do not have selfintersections of $\Sigma$ in that ball, then $\Sigma$ can be written as a graph on $B_{\gamma\cdot\rho}$ and $\gamma$ only depends on the $p$-integrability of the mean curvature, the dimension and the codimension. Let me stress again, that this is a very deep result and probably a massive overshoot for your problem. Hence I only gave it in a comment.

Comment: @humanStampedist Thank you again. I'll have to look into the Theorem and the definitons again, I'm rather ignorant in the matter of geometric measure theory.